# ​ Failed to import “com.r3.corda.jmeter-corda”

Tags: jmeter, corda

I have created an account for Corda developer platform, but failed to access `corda-enterprise`. Maybe this account is not for https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-enterprise, then where can I create the right account? I've also tried `jmeter-corda 4.8`, it still didn't work.

```
plugins {
    //id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir rootProject.file("config/dev")
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    ext.artifactory_contextUrl = 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory'
    ext.artifactory_user = project.ext.getProperty('cordaArtifactoryUsername')
    ext.artifactory_password = project.ext.getProperty('cordaArtifactoryPassword')
    if ( ext.artifactory_user != null && ext.artifactory_password != null ){
        maven{
            url "https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-enterprise"
            credentials {
                username artifactory_user
                password artifactory_password
            }
        }
        maven { url "https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-enterprise-for-customers"
            credentials {
                username artifactory_user
                password artifactory_password
            }
        }
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    // Dependency on Corda Open Source
    maven { url "https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda" }

    // Corda dependencies for the patched Quasar version
    maven { url "https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-dependencies" }
}
dependencies {
    ext.jmeterVersion = 3.3
    ext.cordaVersion = "4.9.1"
    
    compile group: "com.r3.corda", name: "jmeter-corda", version: "4.9.1"
    
    
    compile group: 'org.apache.jmeter', name: 'ApacheJMeter_java', version: jmeterVersion // 'compile' because we extend Java sampler.
    // Dependency on workflows
    compile project(":workflows")
}
```

The error message is:

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':configureCordappFatJar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtime'.
   > Could not resolve com.r3.corda:jmeter-corda:4.9.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.r3.corda:jmeter-corda:4.9.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-enterprise/com/r3/corda/jmeter-corda/4.9.1/jmeter-corda-4.9.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-enterprise/com/r3/corda/jmeter-corda/4.9.1/jmeter-corda-4.9.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server:
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding corda-enterprise jar into my local maven repository and deleted the URL and name/password.